# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error in laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel5.4. I am getting  MethodNotAllowedHttpException when form is submit using ajax. Form method is post and url is define in web routes file. How to resolve this error.

```
web.php 

Route::post('/submit-enquiry','HomeController@submitEnquiry');

register.blade.php

$("#btn-submit").on('click',function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                url: "submit-enquiry",
                data: $('#enquiry-form').serialize()
                }).done(function(result){
//                   if($.isEmptyObject(result.error)){
//                        alert(result.success);
//                    }else{
//                        printErrorMsg(result.error);
//                    } 
                });
        });


Controller 

public function submitEnquiry(Request $request){
        try{
            $params = $request->all();
            $validator = Validator::make($params, [
                'name' => 'required|max:200',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:200',
                'phone' => 'required|max:20',
                'date_of_departure' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
                'return_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d'
            ]);
            if($validator->fails()){
                return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $ex->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding this change `Route::post('/submit-enquiry','HomeController@submitFlightsEnquiry');`

Comment: @Hackerman I have write the same url in web routes file.

Comment: In your route, you have another one `HomeController@submitEnquiry` instead of `HomeController@submitFlightsE‌​nquiry`

Comment: @Hackerman I have already change the function name submitEnquiry

Comment: Do you forget the csrf_token() ?

Comment: Looks like you aren't preventing the default form submit action. I bet your `<form>` tag doesn't have `method="post"`